# Как найти нужную строку в C++?

Tags: c++, строки

К примеру, есть файл `lan.txt`.
В нем записано:

```
Rus.George
{
answer:
1.Здравствуй.
2.Бла-бла.
Dialog:
1.Здравствуй, путешественник.
2.Бла-бла.
}

Eng.George
{
answer:
1.Hello.
2.Bla-bla.
Dialog:
1.Hello, traveler.
2.Bla-bla.
}
```

Суть вопроса:
Как найти нужную строку(например `Rus.George`, а затем вытащить нужный текст)?

Comment: По хорошему - нужно писать парсер, но тут он будет достаточно прост. читать построчно и готово. Но для написания нормального парсера, нужно знать чуточку больше о структуре.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, для твоей задачи этого хватит, далее, ты, конечно, должен будешь нарастить функционал(вот пример алгоритма, если у тебя скобки могут `быть разного типа`):

1. Запускаешь цикл на считывание файла до конца строки
   1.1. Пушим в стек каждую открывающую фигурную скобку(`{`) и попим ее при нахождении закрывающей
   1.2. Если это не фигурные скобки, то проверяем пуст ли стек: если да - то это название элемента, если нет - то мы внутри него.

Comment: Сначала ищем нужно нам имя, затем ищем открывающую и закрывающую скобки?

Comment: Это вообще не важно. Если это не фигурная скобка -> это текст. Если это текст, то ты должен проверить - это внутреннее устройство компонента или это его название. Опять же, соглашусь `KoVadim`, тут желательно было бы увидеть или полное тз или хоть какой-то код.

Comment: Никакого задания нет, развиваюсь. Учусь работать с файлами.

Comment: стек для хранения одной переменной... по модному, по веб3.0ному:)

Comment: @KoVadim Js forever.  Это все схематические наброски, не стоит придираться к реализации. К тому же, в стеке можно хранить структуру. Насчет скобок: они же могут быть разного типа(а могут и не быть).Так что вообще не понял предъявы :)

Comment: С чем мне нужно познакомиться, чтобы это написать?

Comment: Например, с json'ом:)